# UIViewController with UITableView and TextField storyboard placement

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

This might be a simple question but using storyboard I can't seem to position my table, a message field and a button correctly.  In the picture below, if it's positioned that way, only then do I get to see the text field and button at the bottom of the screen and the table view takes up the rest of the screen.  If I drag the text field and button to the bottom and resize the table, the text field and button disappear and the table is cut off.  Why is that?  Is there a solution to this without doing it programmatically?

[image: sample pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution is to remove all constraints then position them where you want them.

You'll find you get different effect when try to reposition items depending where you drag from for example double tap an item and nudge it with arrow keys or grab the middle to move it resizing via the corners.

But in my opinion it's easier remove all constraints from the view and then set them as you go.

Also you might want to consider using a container view for the table view and have a separate UItableViewController that way you can easily separate out that the tableview logic from the other ViewController. It will help stop things getting a little messy later on as project grows.